# Can I apply AWS FindMatch transform on dataframe ? If yes then how

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-glue

I wanted to find out if I can apply the FindMatch ml transform in AWS Glue on a spark dataframe. Currently I can use it on a dynamicframe. Below is the syntax if i want to use the findmatch transform on a dynamic frame.

```
<output DynamicFrame on which the ml transform has been applied> = 
FindMatches.apply(frame = <Input DynamicFrame>, transformId = <transformation 
id of the findmatch ml transform created separately>)
```

I have tried using a dataframe in place of the input dynamic frame and when I run the Glue job, it fails. Error shown is as below

"Attribute Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'glue_ctx'"

Below is the code i tried where i tried using a dataframe

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglueml.transforms import FindMatches

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "hospitality", table_name = 
"personinputdata", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
df0 = datasource0.toDF()

resolvechoice1 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasource0, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = 
"hospitality", table_name = "personinputdata", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice1")

findmatchdf = FindMatches.apply(frame = df0, transformId = "tfm- 
01cc9b02c93640cfc7ce5ea91745e24258cb2e01")
findmatchdf.show()
```

And below is the code when instead of a dataframe i tried using a dynamicframe and the code works.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglueml.transforms import FindMatches

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "hospitality", table_name = 
"patientinputdata", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

resolvechoice1 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasource0, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = 
"hospitality", table_name = "patientinputdata", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice1")

findmatches2 = FindMatches.apply(frame = resolvechoice1, transformId = "tfm- 
0cadd1e6d2da40d7c18db7836e92be93833b6019", transformation_ctx = "findmatches2")
```

I tried searching online if I could find the code for FindMatch ml transform but could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindMatch works on dynamic frames only as you already know...
So you can convert your spark df to dynamic frame whenever you want to run it

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
Dyf0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df0, glueContext, "anyname")
```

And then run your FindMatch as required.